# sending newsletter with swift 4.1.1

Tags: php, swiftmailer, newsletter

I would create a php newsletter script with SwiftMail 4.1.1 but I have only founded the wiki for Swift v.3 at http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/sending/batch 
For Swift 4.1.1 there isn't wiki http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v4/start

How can I do with for Swift v.4? The same code for v.3 is not working.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $recipients = new Swift_RecipientList(); this class is not present

Comment: Can't you just create an array of email addresses and provide to batchSend method? i.e. without creating new Swift_RecipientList() ?

Comment: Can you give me an example code for batchSend Method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does *there isn't wiki* mean exactly? The link you post does point to a wiki entry titled *Swift Mailer Version 4*. Furthermore, there's a big [Complete User Guide](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html) link on the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as per your request -

If you want to send emails in a batch

As per latest documentation at 
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

Sending Emails in Batch¶

If you want to send a separate message to each recipient so that only their own address shows up in the To: field, follow the following recipe:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

//Send the message
$failedRecipients = array();
$numSent = 0;
$to = array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name');

foreach ($to as $address => $name)
{
  $message->setTo(array($address => $name));
  $numSent += $this->send($message, $failedRecipients);
}

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
```

---

Using batchSend() - which I am not sure if is available in in your required version or not?

```
$mailer_instance = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($mail_transport_instance);
$message_instance = Swift_Message::newInstance()
      ->setSubject($subject)
      //Set the From address with an associative array
      ->setFrom($mail_from)
      //Set the To addresses with an associative array
      ->setTo($mail_to);
      //some other options as required

$num_sent = $mailer_instance->batchSend($message_instance);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I download Swift 4.1.1 from swiftmailer.org. Is batchSend avaliable? How can I retrieve the address mail where sending mail fails? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use the 1st method above (i.e. without batchSend() )?  $failedReceipients is updated with the emails where sending fails.

Comment: I try to set an invalid email in $to array but failedRecipients is empty and numSend count it as an email sent. In my box I have a failure mailer daemon. what is the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Swiftmailer 4 has been rewritten, the class `Swift_RecipientList` is not available in Swiftmailer 4.

See the documentation for [Swiftmailer 4 about Sending Messages](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/doc/sending.rst), there is a section named *Sending Emails in Batch*, maybe that's what you're looking for.